# Download file from local folder

Tags: python, flask

I am trying this code

```
@app.route('/process/<user_id>/<file_format>/<download>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def download(user_id, file_format, download):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+socket.gethostname()+"app/documents/"+ download)
        html = response.read()
        return html
```

But i am getting:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

If i do only  `response = urllib2.urlopen("app/documents/"+ download)`

I get:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: app/documents/thereport_1712818a-39a3-436e-985c-84f1e8d43346.pdf
```

So, basically how can i get the file from my document folder?

Comment: ... socket.gethostname()+"/app ... ?

Comment: @sunn0, well now i am getting not found. The file is saved here  path="app/documents/"+doc_name where doc_name is equal to doc_name = "thereport_" + str(rand) + "." + format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/process/<user_id>/<file_format>/<download>')
def download(user_id, file_format, download):
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='documents/'+download))
```

This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I understand you want to download a html file located on your own machine.
First:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+socket.gethostname()+"app/documents/"+ download)
```

should be

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://"+socket.gethostname()+"/app/documents/"+ download)
```

unless 'app' is part of your hostname (which I don't think it is).

Second... make sure you can do the same thing using wget (which means you have a http server installed locally, which listens on port 80 and can serve the requested file):

```
wget <URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process/<user_id>/<file_format>/<download>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def download(user_id, file_format, download):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect("http://{0}/app/documents/{1}".format(request.host,download))
```

Comment: output is not found http: //127.0.0.1:5000/app/documents/thereport_003e4242-9cff-410b-8258-db1cfa9fb7c8.pdf

Comment: That's another problem. Your file isn't there, mainly because you need to put it in the static directory.

Comment: If i don't have your route (app/documents), obviously i will get 404.